# R Shiny: How do I create an empty editable table to allow user input & draw updated scatterplot?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

This is the reproducible code I generated:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput('x1'),
    textOutput("text"),
    plotOutput("plot")

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    x = iris[,1:2] # only take sepal length & sepal width 
    y <- reactive(x)

    output$x1 = renderDT(x, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)

    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')

    observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col
      v = info$value
      x[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, x[i, j])
      replaceData(proxy, x, resetPaging = FALSE)  
    })

    output$text <- renderText({
      y()[1, 1]
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(y(),aes(x=y()[,1], y=y()[,2])) + geom_point()
    })

  }
)
```

This app has a table that is editable, and a scatterplot below that plots the data.

I tested that the table is indeed being updated in this snippet of code:

```
output$text <- renderText({
      y()[1, 1]
    })
```

Whenever I update the 1st number (row 1, column 1) in the table, the text get updated as well.

My 2 questions are:

1. Right now the plot is not being properly updated as the table. For example, if I change any number in Sepal.Width column to be a very large number (e.g. 5000), the scatterplot is not being updated. Is there anything wrong in the reactivity part?
2. Right now I am testing using Iris dataset since it is very straightforward. Ideally i would like to have a blank table at initiation, and leave the table completely editable for users to input data through using library(DT). Is this idea feasible in Shiny?

Much appreciation for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem was the generation of `y`. It is a reactive, but `x` is not, so it doesn't get updated when you change `x`. Therefore I now use a `reactiveValues` object and directly update this object.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput('x1'),
    textOutput("text"),
    plotOutput("plot")
    
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    x = iris[,1:2] # only take sepal length & sepal width 
    y <- reactiveValues(data = x)
    
    output$x1 = renderDT(y$data, selection = 'none', editable = TRUE)
    
    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')
    
    observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col
      v = info$value
      y$data[i, j] <- DT::coerceValue(v, y$data[i, j])
      replaceData(proxy, y$data, resetPaging = FALSE)  
    })
    
    output$text <- renderText({
      y$data[1, 1]
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(y$data, aes(x=y$data[,1], y=y$data[,2])) + geom_point()
    })
    
  }
)
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to show a completely empty table with `DT` For a more "excel" like table in `shiny` have a look at [`rhandsontable`](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/).